# passing parameters between controllers by using $rootscope?

Tags: parameters, rootscope

i'm new to angular js and web applications in general. i've been exchanging parameters between controllers through broadcast/emit/listeners, but i think it is just too complicated. i have to code a lot just to send/receive a parameter to/from another controller. i read a reply about this subject in this forum and a guy said it isn't a good idea to use $rootscope to do this. i wonder why, since it is the top-most scope. what would its purpose be, then? how long will a given variable be alive in $rootscope? only as long as the task that populated it is running? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use $rootScope to store data that is common between controllers, this pollutes the namespace and has other issues when handling isolate scopes.

Use [Angular services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to share data between controllers. Set up one service for the data you want to share and inject it into multiple controllers.